# How to delete schedule jobs through Enterprise Manager oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-enterprise-manager

I am using oracle database 11g. I created 2 schedule jobs of backup through Enterprise Manager. Now when I delete jobs then I am getting following error

```
The specified job, job run or execution is still active. It must finish running, or be stopped before it can be deleted. Filter on status 'Active' to see active executions.
```

How to delete jobs?

Answer (score 0):

To forcefully drop the Job even if it is running then Use the following code:

```
dbms_scheduler.drop_job (<job_name>, force => true);
```

To drop the job after it complete its current execution work, Use the following code:

```
dbms_scheduler.drop_job (<job_name>, defer => true);
```

Cheers!!